# Pytorch : how to run code on several machines in cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, nlp, pytorch

I am using a cluster to train a recurrent neural network developed using PyTorch. PyTorch automatically threads, which allows to use all the cores of a machine in parallel without having to explicitly program for it. This is great !

Now when I try to use several nodes at the same time using a script like this one :

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -N comparison_of_architecture
#$ -pe mvapich2-rostam 32
#4 -tc 4
#$ -o /scratch04.local/cnelias/Deep-Jazz/logs/out_comparison_training.txt
#$ -e /scratch04.local/cnelias/Deep-Jazz/logs/err_comparison_training.txt
#$ -t 1
#$ -cwd
```

I see that 4 nodes are being used but only one is actually doing work, so "only" 32 cores are in use.

I have no knowledge of parallel programming and I don't understand a thing in the tutorial provided on PyTorch's website, I am afraid this is completely out of my scope.

Are you aware of a simple way to let a PyTorch program run on several machines without having to explicitly program the exchanges of the messages and computation between these machines ?

PS : I unfortunately don't have a GPU and the cluster I am using also doesn't, otherwise I would have tried it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/dist_tuto.html#distributed-training) from the pytorch website?

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** There is no easy solution.

There are two ways how you can parallelize training of a deep learning model. The most commonly used is data parallelism (as opposed to model parallelism). In that case, you have a copy of the model on each device, run the model and back-propagation on each device independently and get the weight gradients. Now, the tricky part begins. You need to collect all gradients at a single place, sum them (differentiation is linear w.r.t. summation) and do the optimizer step. The optimizer computes the weight updates and you need to tell each copy of your model how to update the weights.

PyTorch can somehow do this for multiple GPUs on a single machine, but as far as I know, there is no ready-made solution to do this on multiple machines.

Comment: Apparently there is a way to use DistributedDataParallel for CPUs as well but the tutorial is garbage and I have found no other resource on the internet :/